# How to convert json to pojo with specific fields

Tags: java, json, jackson

I tried to convert this json (it's a response from google people api) to pojo. i get null instead of object with data. i think my pojo is not correct and jackson cant convert it

```
{
"resourceName": "people/113175645456469629209",
"etag": "%EgoBAj0DBgk+NTcuGgQBAgnfvtrUH",
"names": [
    {
        "metadata": {
            "primary": true,
            "source": {
                "type": "PROFILE",
                "id": "113175645456469629209"
            }
        },
        "displayName": "firstName lastName",
        "familyName": "lastName",
        "givenName": "firstName",
        "displayNameLastFirst": "firstName, lastName",
        "unstructuredName": "firstName, lastName"
    }
]
}
```

I want to get only pojo with first name and last name

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import org.springframework.social.google.api.plus.Person;

public class CustomPerson {

    @JsonProperty("names")
    private CustomPerson.Names names;

    public CustomPerson() {
    }

    public String getGivenName() {
        return this.names == null ? null : this.names.givenName;
    }

    public String getFamilyName() {
        return this.names == null ? null : this.names.familyName;
    }

    private static class Names {
        @JsonProperty
        private String givenName;
        @JsonProperty
        private String familyName;

        private Names() {
        }
    }
}
```

any advice would help me

Answer (score 1):

```
public class CustomPerson {

    @JsonProperty
    private List<CustomPerson.Names> names;

    public CustomPerson() {
    }

    private static class Names {
        @JsonProperty
        private String givenName;
        @JsonProperty
        private String familyName;

        private Names() {
        }

        public String getGivenName() {
            return this.names == null ? null : this.names.givenName;
        }

        public String getFamilyName() {
            return this.names == null ? null : this.names.familyName;
        }
    }
}
```